# Spartacus: Override cx-update-profile to add/modify input fields in PersonalDetails

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Am trying to modify Personal details page in myaccount, i want to add new input fields, remove some existing input fields, how to achieve this, appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General way of replacing a CMS component

- find the flexType of the component, or the component typecode from the /pages request in your browser tools - network tab.
- generate a module and a component with the ng-cli (`ng g m your-profile-details` followed by `ng g c your-profile-details`
- configure your component to be used https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/#page-title
- copy the entire HTML from the OOTB source code
- in the *component.ts file, you extend the OOTB component `extends XXComponent`
- sometimes you have to copy the implementation as well, depending on the visibility of the attributes / functions in the OOTB component.

Run `yarn run start` and verify if your component is now in use!

Modify your component HTML to your liking.